# MOSFETs in charge circuit having different characteristics

Tags: mosfet

A few of the products at work are suffering from a shortage of a particular PMOSFET ([IRLML6402](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml6402.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668c9822638)) and so I have been provided an alternative ([DMP2305U](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31737.pdf)) to use. I changed a few over on a few products to see if it would make any difference to the workings of the circuit, and all seemed fine.

I then came to one of the products that has a rechargeable NiMH battery. This works by having a microprocessor switching the MOSFET on and off to regulate current flow. A small snippet of that circuit can be seen here:

[image]

As this is a work product, I cannot show any more of it (I am aware the PFET says it is an SI2301, bit the one fitted is the IRLML, this version of the schematic wasn't updated). The source of the FET recieves power from a USB.

Now, onto the results. I powered it up using an Agilent power analyser, with the power going in to the USB, and I monitored the current drawn by the circuit. With the original FET fitted (IRMLM6402), during the charging stage, there is a nice constant (average) 260mA. When I fitted the replacement (DMP2305U), this then changed to 280mA. I tried a few times, and the result was repeatable. I then changed the FET back over, just to be certain it was the FET responsible, and when the original was fitted back, 260mA was seen again.

I have scoured through the datasheet and have no idea why this would happen. There are a lot of factors I don't understand, as I am still learning electronics, so I cannot see why this change in current consumption would happen. Does anyone know any factors that could cause this?

This does not affect the working of the circuit in any way, I am just curious as to why this happens, so I know what sort of things to look out for in future when testing replacement components.

Comment: Probably the difference is \$R_\mathrm{DS}\$. The replacement part has higher \$R_\mathrm{DS}\$ so the voltage drop across it is greater, so more current is needed in the converter. As a guess.

Comment: I had considered that, but the difference is pretty small, and I wouldn't have thought it would be enough to account for a 20mA change?

Comment: It's pretty large - 60 m\$\Omega\$ vs. 50 m\$\Omega\$, that's 20% (at -4.5 \$\mathrm{V_{GS}}\$)

Comment: That's under different test conditions. The closest one would be at test condition Vgs=-2.5V Id=-3.1 for the IRLML part, and Vgs = -2.5V Id = -3.4A for the DMP part. Under those conditions, the DPM part actually has a lower Rds (60mOhm vs 80mOhm)

Comment: DMP is higher at -2.5 V as well (90 m\$\Omega\$).

Comment: If you look at the -4.5V Vgs, then again, the DMP part seems lower to me... 45mOhm typical and 60mOhm max, vs the IRLML 50mOhm typical and 65mOhm max

Comment: @awjlogan it is if you look at the maximum and compare it to the typical of the other. If you compare typical and max, the DMP seems to be lower

Comment: And even that surely wouldn't account for a 20mA difference?

Comment: sure, I was going on the headline figure :) Have you tried a different DMP2305? The 20 mA isn't so surprising if you're close to the limit of Vin.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried 2 of each, consistent results

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at the gate charge and not big enough to make a difference, which is why I deleted my comment.  I think you need a scope on Vgs and Vds for both parts to debug what's actually happening.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don;t know enough about them to really know what I am looking for. Am I looking for a difference in voltage, and where should I expect that? I'll be leaving work soon so will have to continue tomorrow.... But any ideas or knowledge is appreciated. It's really stumped me!

Comment: What is setting the constant current? It is hard to help without the full schematic. Is L2 part of a buck converter? When you say charging state, does that mean Q2 is fully on? Is any current flowing through R2 / D2?

Comment: I'm not allowed to provide any more unfortunately. L2 is indeed part of a buck converter. R2/D2 is only in use during trickle charge, and the current is set by the switching speed which is controlled by the micro. It adjusts the switching speed to set charging current. Note the current I'm measuring is the circuit consumption, not the charging current

Comment: Is there any feedback of the charging current to the micro, or is it running open loop?

Comment: It measure the battery voltage and temperature and changes the charge current accordingly between fast, top off and trickle I believe

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please explain what their reason was so I can improve the question?